# Connection to Asustor NAS in Chrome is blocked

Tags: google-chrome, nas

I have an Asustor NAS connected to my router, on a Mac Studio. The router shows the unit as connected, with IP address 192.168.0.102.

If I open that URL in my Chrome browser, I get a page that says 'This site can't be reached. 192.168.0.102 refused to connect.' This happens if I use port 8000 (http) or 8001 (https).

I can connect to the NAS with Finder, and see the data stored on it, so the device is connected and responding, but I cannot connect to the OS (called ADM) through the browser.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: I have been trying to access the same page on different browsers. Chrome doesn't work; Safari doesn't work; Edge doesn't work; but Firefox DOES work. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to believe this. When Chrome says the site can't be reached,  all you have to do is enter the text 'thisisunsafe' anywhere in the browser window. This bypasses the Chrome security features.

See https://cybercafe.dev/thisisunsafe-bypassing-chrome-security-warnings/